# Unable to submit the form on ajax success function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

**My contact form has google captcha. I have to submit the form after the captcha validation. Here is my jquery code. I validate correctly. But my problem is, i could not submit the form while the result is true.**

```
jQuery('#citygreen-contact-us-submit').on('click',function(){
  var contact_us_form = jQuery("#contact-us-form");
     jQuerythis=jQuery(this);
        jQueryfeedback_loader=jQuery("#contact-us-loader");
        jQueryfeedback_status=jQuery("#contact-us-status");
        jQueryfeedback_loader.show();
        jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: ajax_url,
           dataType: 'json',
           data: "action=contact_us_validator&"+contact_us_form.serialize(),
           success  : function(result) {
              jQueryfeedback_loader.hide();
              alert(result.status);
              if(result.status == 'true') {
                 contact_us_form.submit();
              }
              else {
                 jQueryfeedback_status.addClass("error");
                 jQueryfeedback_status.html(result.message).slideDown();
                 Recaptcha.reload();
              }
           },
           error: function(testObj) {
              alert("Try Again Later");
           }
        });

     return false;
});
```

Comment: whats the problem? and where is ajax_url set?

Comment: Where is `ajax_url` defined ?

Comment: Please provide html of the form and also whole script, not just the part you think the problem might exist.

Comment: Is `result.status` (string) `"true"` or (boolean) `true`?

Comment: result.status is "true". Its a string. Not a boolean.

Comment: ajax_url is "http://www.citygreen.com/beta/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

Comment: my problem is contact_us_form.submit(); not working on the success function.

Comment: Does it really goes inside the statement if(result.status == 'true') {
Try alerting it there.And  dataType is jsonp for outbound ajax requests

Comment: could you show us your HTML? maybe there is something wrong

Comment: DataType Jsonp alerts error.

Comment: `<form id="contact-us-form" action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">Company Name<input id="company" type="text" name="company" size="20" maxlength="40" /> Phone<input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" size="20" maxlength="40" /><?php $publickey = "6Lee8NsSAAAqftg"; echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey); ?><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="citygreen-contact-us-submit"/></form>`

Answer (score 0):

I found Another plugin like captcha which one can validate using jquery. I gives the solution to overcome this problem.

```
[Real Person Plugin]http://keith-wood.name/realPerson.html
```

**JQuery Function :**

```
function rpHash(value) { 
    var hash = 5381; 
    value = value.toUpperCase(); 
    for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) { 
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + value.charCodeAt(i);
    } 
    return hash; 
}
```